# Lightest way of zooming in CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, zooming

I have an image, that has to zoom slowly to about `transform: scale(2,2)` with a duration of 300 seconds. The problem is, if I do it with an CSS animation, the page starts lagging. So my question is, what is the lightest way for an infinite zoom animation? CSS or javascript (jQuery).

Comment: so by lightest you mean most performant?

Comment: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm

Comment: Most performant yes. I looked into your link, but translate3d is for moving objects. I already made use of transform:scale(), but that resulted in a lot of lagg.

Comment: you misunderstood. translate3d is just used to make use of hardware acceleration, but wont actually style

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=translate3d%20hardware%20acceleration

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
img {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

.5s <- time duration

Comment: It's not a hover, but a continuous animation. And transform scale is the part that makes the webpage lagg so much. I already tried the CSS animation, jQuery classchange and more.